# Is the cardinality of a Group is equal to the number of cosets of one of it's subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Assume I have $H \subseteq G$

It seems to me that since the right cosets of $H$ from a partition of $G$ then the cardinality of the set: $\{Hg_1, Hg_2,\dots, Hg_n\}$ (not necessarily finite)

Must be that of $G$.

is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that the set of cosets of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ are a partition of $G$.  However, two cosets $H x$ and $H y$ can be the same even if $x \not= y$ since we could have $x = h y$ where $h \in H$.

What is true in general is that the cardinality of $G$ is equal to the cardinality of $(G / H) \times H$ (where $G / H$ is the **set** of cosets of $H$ in $G$).

Comment: A partition is by definition a union of disjoint sets, if x = hy then it must be that  $x \in Hx $ and $x \in Hy$ not disjoint.

Comment: @Makogan $H x$ and $H y$ are always either equal or disjoint.  The point is that you can get the same coset from different representatives $x \in G$ so while the set of cosets is a partition, it isn't indexed by all elements of $G$.  You have to choose some set of representatives from all distinct cosets.  Two cosets $H x$ and $H y$ are the same if and only if $x = h y$ for some $h$.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake you are making is counting the whole subgroup $H$ as one element.  Imagine you have many cartons and packed all your books in the cartons all having equal number of books. The number of books in your possession *is not the number of cartons* (Unless you pack one book in each carton, and this is the point in the answer by m10105).

Comment: I have been told that all cosets of a subgroup are disjoint, so then it must be that for every $g$ the coest $gH$ must count as an independent element no?

Answer (score 2):

Except in special cases, no. The obvious special case is when $H = \{1\}$.

Here is an easy counter-example. Take $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H = 2\mathbb{Z}$. We have that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

Note that as $G = \mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, the left and right cosets of $G$ with respect to $H$ are the same.

Comment: I am confused, the cardinality of the even integers is the same as the cardinality of the integers, why is this a counter example? i.e the cardinality of {1H, 2H, 3H.... \inf H} is that of the naturals

Comment: Note that $|H|$ and $[G : H]$ are not necessarily the same. The number of cosets is $[G : H]$. So while $H = 2\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite, there are only two cosets: $\{ 0, 1 \}$, where the coset $0$ contains the even integers and the coset $1$ contains the odd integers.