# Is Lagrange group theorem still valid for infinite groups?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, cardinals, infinite-groups

So it is a well know result that the quotient space $G/\cal R$ corresponding to right congruent relation $\cal R$ is equipotent to the quotient space $G/\cal L$ corresponding to the left congruent relation $\cal L$ so that is it is usual to use the simbol $|G:H|$ to indicate the cardinal correspondint to the two above quotient spaces.

So let's we prove the following theorem.

> **Theorem** -Lagrange's Theorem
>
> If $(H,\star)$ is a subgroup of a finite group $(G,\star)$ then the equality
> $$
> |G|=|H|\cdot|G:H|
> $$
> holds.
>
> *Proof*. So we know that the quotient space of any equivalence relation is a partition so that the equality
> $$
> |G|=\sum_{X\in G/\mathcal L}|X|
> $$
> holds but for any $X\in G/\mathcal L$ there exists $x\in G$ such that
> $$
> X=xH
> $$
> so that actually for any $X\in G/\mathcal L$ the equality
> $$
> |X|=|H|
> $$
> holds and thus finally we conclude that
> $$
> |G|=\sum_{X\in G/\mathcal L}|X|=\sum_{X\in G/\mathcal L}|H|=|H|\cdot|G/\mathcal L|=|H|\cdot|G:H|
> $$
> as we desired.

So I would know why the last theorem is only true for finite groups: indeed, by cardinal arithmetic we know that the cardinality of **any** disjoint union is just (by definition, right?) the sum of cardinality of addends and just by the cardinal arithmetic we know that if $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ are cardinal the equality
$$
\sum_{\alpha\in\lambda}\kappa=\kappa\cdot\lambda
$$
holds. Moreover, I point out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2701241/736008) it seems implicitly that the above theorem is still valid for infinite group but unfortunately I did not find any textbook which say this so that I thought to put a specific question. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Yes, it holds for all groups and subgroups. The finiteness assumption is not needed. Although it is not that useful for infinite groups. In particular if $G$ and $H$ are both infinite (of equal cardinality) then it doesn't tell us anything about $[G:H]$, unlike finite case. That's why it is mostly used in finite setup.

Comment: @freakish Perfect: all clear. Thanks very much for the comment! :-)