# Why does the equality $\langle x\rangle=\{x^{-1},1,x\}$ not generally hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, cyclic-groups

So if $X$ is a not empty subset of a group $(G,\cdot,1)$ then the collection
$$
\mathcal X:=\{H\in\mathcal P(X):H\,\text{subgroup containing X}\}
$$
is not empty since it contains $G$ and moreover its intersection $\langle X\rangle$ is the most little subgroup containing $X$. Now let's we observe that the collection
$$
H_x:=\{x^{-1},1,x\}
$$
is a subgroup containing $x$ since it contains the unit $1$ and as well the inverse of any its element and since it is closed with respect the operation $\cdot$ defined in $G$. So I observe that if $x$ is in $\langle x\rangle$ then surely its inverse $x^{-1}$ is there contained as obviously the unit so that the inclusion
$$
H_x\subseteq\langle x\rangle
$$
holds but if $H_x$ is a subgroup containing $x$ then even the inclusion
$$
\langle x\rangle\subseteq H_x
$$
must holds and thus finally the equality
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}\langle x\rangle =H_x
$$
holds. Now really many (all actually) authors says that $G$ is cyclic if there exists $x\in G$ such that
$$
G=\langle x\rangle
$$
so that if what we above observe was true then any cyclic group must have at least three elements and this seems to me really stranger because consulting the Web I understood that this cannot be: so I thought to put a specific question where I ask clarification why \eqref{1} does not holds. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: The flaw is simple: $H_x$ is not (in general) closed under the operation in $G$, since for example $x^2$ is not (guaranteed to be) in $H_x$.

Comment: Concrete example: $x=1\in\Bbb Z = G$. Then $H_1 = \{-1,0,1\}$, but $1+1=2\not\in H_1$, so $H_1$ is not a subgroup

Comment: @Milten Oh, right: what stupid! Unfortunately today I am not on the top form: thanks for the check!

Comment: I don't fully get your questions. Why do you say "any cyclic group must have at least three elements"? $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{ 0,1\}$ only has 2 elements. For $\langle x \rangle$, the cyclic group is the smallest group containing $x$, so if you have another group $H_x$ containing $x$, then $\langle x \rangle \subseteq H_x$.  Maybe I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @MathFail Well, if what I observed was true then it held the equality $$G=H_x$$ but if $x$ is not equal to $1$ then $H_x$ can have at most tree elements, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the equality does not hold in general, it suffices to provide a single counterexample.

Consider $G=(\Bbb Z, +)$. The identity of $G$ is $0$. Also, $1\in G$ with inverse $-1\in G$. Therefore, we have

$$H_1=\{-1,0,1\}.$$

But $1+1=2\notin H_1$, so $H_1$ cannot be a group as it is not closed. (All subgroups are themselves groups.)

In fact, $\langle 1\rangle=G$.

Comment: Perfect: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for the counterexample! See you soon. :-)

Comment: You're welcome, @AntonioMariaDiMauro. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as Milten observed into the comments above, $H_x$ is not a subgroup since $x^2$ is not in $H_x$ which so is not closed: e.g $H_3$ is not a subgroup of $(\Bbb R,\cdot)$. Moreover, we can observe that if there exsists a prime number $p\in\Bbb N_+\setminus\{1\}$ such that
$$
|G|=p
$$
then for any $x\in G\setminus\{1\}$ the equality
$$
G=\langle x\rangle
$$
holds: indeed, we know (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4646780/736008) for details) that
$$
|G|=\big|\langle x\rangle\big|\cdot\big|G:\langle x\rangle\big|
$$
so that if $x$ is not $1$ and so $\langle x\rangle$ is not the trivial subgroup $\{1\}$ then  necessarly
$$
\big|\langle x\rangle\big|=p\quad\text{and}\quad\big|G:\langle x\rangle\big|=1
$$
so that $G$ is just $\langle x\rangle$ and this proves the existence of a class of not trivial cyclic subgroups, that is the class of finite groups with prime order.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144350/discussion-on-answer-by-antonio-maria-di-mauro-why-does-the-equality-langle-x); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.